# How difficult is Eldritch Horror with differing numbers of players?

Tags: eldritch-horror

Removing the element of how easy or hard it is to work as a group, and assuming that you are 1 player controlling all 1 to 8 players, what numbers of players are easier or harder to win Eldritch Horror, and roughly how much easier or difficult? I don't expect statistically significant replies, just interested in what people's impressions are by feel.

It already seems evident that playing with 1, 3, 5, or 7 players is a disadvantage due to the number of clues spawned, gates spawned, and monsters surging being identical to those for player-counts one greater.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jump from 4 players to 5 players seems to makes the game tougher. While stronger monster surges start at 3 players, it's easier to cover the entire world with a 4 player team. I find gates spawning is the most dangerous issue that needs to be dealt with since leaving gates open will help advance doom. Having extra monsters is also bad, but some monsters will sit quietly until you go deal with them. A few cards look at how many monsters are on the map, so you don't want to let the total number of monsters to get to hight. That being said, monsters that move to expedition locations often don't have retribution effects and tend to be ignored in many of the games I've played.

If you have Akachi as one of your investigators, she can control where the next gate spawns by using her ability to look at the top two gate locations and putting one of them on top of the stack and one on the bottom. I'm not sure how powerful this strategy is, but it certainly is an option in a four player game. Once you get that second gate spawning, it's no longer an effective strategy.

If you want to alter the difficulty of the game and make it easier, I suggest altering the mythos deck and removing the hard mythos cards that have tentacles. Then build your mythos deck from the remaining cards. To make the game harder, you can remove all of the easy mythos cards. The mythos cards that come up heavily effect the difficulty of the game.

Comment: I agree.  Mythos has more to do with the real difficulty of the game.  If you're playing a specific number of investigators as one player, you'll know where you want everyone to go and what they should do.  That game then becomes a formula with some random numbers thrown in.  It's something you can (theoretically) solve.

Answer (score 2):

There are some statistic available [on average difficulties](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ArNdOESpLXrNdE5obElscWdwU2JwQ1JPQXJVZ3ZfRlE&usp=drive_web#gid=15) and [on doom track levels vs number of players](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ArNdOESpLXrNdE5obElscWdwU2JwQ1JPQXJVZ3ZfRlE&usp=drive_web#gid=6).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the difficulty on changes with which enemy you fight. The game scales that it stays the same difficulty with the same enemy against a different amount of players.

I have played several enemies against a different size of group. We won the first time with a group of 3 and lost the second time with a group of 5 against enemy A. With enemy B we lost with a group of 4 but won with a group of 7. In my experience the amount of players don't change the difficulty.